# AWS Glue won't Classify my Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, logstash-grok, aws-glue

I have a html file which structured like this:

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0transitional//en">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="Author" content="ERA">
<LINK REL=STYLESHEET TYPE="text/css" HREF="Style_Sheets/ERA_Internet_Printer.css">
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<font face="courier new" size=-4>                                                                                          14V-IG-TEST-DATA - SERVC - EXEC# 4515 
                                                                                          [11| Blubb,abcons, Port: 18 For: abcons

                                                                           For period : GE 08/04/18 AND LE 11/04/18 OR GE 11/04/18 AND LE 11/05/18 
                                                                                             01:45:40  11-04-18  -  Page #    1 


Serial#........................ 564561215
Make Desc...................... VW
Carline........................ MUX
Year...........................  2015
Cust#  ........................     512
License#....................... 78365HH
Open RO........................ R25625
EOR............................ EOR

Serial#........................ 2151512315
Make Desc...................... VOLKSWAGEN
Carline........................ VOLKSWAGEN
Year...........................  2017
Cust#  ........................     552
License#....................... DPA2151
Open RO........................ T52165
EOR............................ EOR
2 records listed.
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get the Information out of the file like "Key.......... Value".
So I've created a custom classifier in AWS Glue with Grok to get the Info.
The classifier is configured like this:
[Custom Classifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vepPT.png)

So the Grok Pattern is configured as followed:

```
%{KEY:mykey}%{GREEDYDATA:myvalue}
```

with the custom Pattern:

```
KEY ([a-zA-Z# 1-9]+\.+ )
```

Every Grok online debugger (like https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) get the information out of the data structure with this configuration. But when I start the crawler in Glue with the custom classifier, it won't find any tables or structures.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I think you're running into the problem I answered here: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/issues/4

There's a buried sentence in AWS documentation that states "To reclassify data to correct an incorrect classifier, create a new crawler with the updated classifier"

Simply updating the classifier and re-running the crawler will not use the updated classifier.