# AWS Glue classifier for extracting JSON array values

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue

I have files in S3 with inline JSON per line of the structure:

```
{ "resources": [{"resourceType":"A","id":"A",...},{...}] }
```

If I run glue over it, I get "resource: array" as the top level element. I want however the elements of the array to be inspected and used as the top level table elements. All the elements per *resources* array will have the same schema. So I expect

```
resourceType: string
id: string
....
```

Theoretically, a custom JSON classifier should handle this:

```
$.resources[*]
```

However, the path is not picked up. So I still get the resources:array as the top level element.

I could now run some pre-processing to extract the array elements myself and write them  line per line. However, I want to understand why my path is not working.

**UPDATE 1:**

It might be something with the JSON that I do not understand (its valid JSON produced via JAVA Jackson). If I remove the outer object with the *resources* attribute and change the structure to

```
[{"resourceType":"A","id":"A",...},{...}]
```

the classifier `$[*]` should pick the sub-objects up. But I still get *array:arra*y as top level element.

**UPDATE 2:**

Its indeed a formatting issue. If I change the JSON files to

```
[
  {"resourceType":"A","id":"A",...},{...}
]
```

`$[*]` starts to work.

**UPDATE 3:**

Its however **not** fixing the issue with `$.resources[*]` to reformat to

```
{
    "resources": [
        {"resourceType":"A","id":"A",...},{...}
    ]
}
```

**UPDATE 4:**

If I take my file and run it through a Intellij re-format, hence produce a JSON object where all nested elements have line breaks, it also starts working with `$.resources[*]`. Basically, like in UPDATE 3 just applied down the structure.

```
{
    "resources": [
        {
          "resourceType":"A",
          "id":"A"
        },
        {
          ...
        }
    ]
}
```

What bothers me is, that the requirements regarding the structure are still not clear to me, since UPDATE 2 worked, but not UPDATE 3. I also find nowhere in the documentation a formal requirement regarding the JSON structure.

In this sense, I think I got to the conclusion of my own question, but the systematics stay a bit unclear.

Comment: I found this discussion which highlights that a update of a classifier might need to re-create the corresponding crawler: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49995877/aws-glue-wont-classify-my-data

In order to rule this out, I created a new classifier and new job. This did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To conclude here:

The issue is related to unclear documented JSON formatting requirements of Glue.

A normalisation via `json.dumps(my_json, separators=(',',':'))` produces compact JSON that works for my use case.

I normalised now the content via a lambda.

Lambda code as reference for whomever it may help:

```
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')

    pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket=my_bucket)
    
    for page in pages:
        try:
            contents = page["Contents"]
        except KeyError:
            break

        for obj in contents:
            key = obj["Key"]
            obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=my_bucket, Key=key)
            j = json.loads(obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
            
            new_json = json.dumps(j, separators=(',',':'))
                
            target = 'nrmlzd/' + key
                
            s3.put_object(
                Body=new_json,
                Bucket=my_bucket,
                Key= target
            )
```

Comment: Could I ask what does the compact do ?

Comment: Basically removing whitespaces, tabs and new lines. Creating a one line JSON.

Comment: what's the benefit to have one line JSON, please?

Comment: JSON serialization libraries require each record to be placed on a separate line, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/parsing-JSON.html